# How am I supposed to use ArucoInvoke.EstimatePoseSingleMarkers()? - Updated

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have a half working Monogame based Emgu.CV code, which is supposed to use the Aruco marker No. 21 for pose estimation.
The plan is to use this marker, estimate its pose then draw some fancy 3d object on it.
My problem is I can't use ArucoInvoke.EstimatePoseSingleMarkers because I can't figure out what structure is for cameramatrix and coeffs.

`ArucoInvoke.EstimatePoseSingleMarkers(_corners, 0.1f, cameraMatrix, coeffs, rvecs, tvecs);`

_corners comes from the detection phase where it is used for image wrap on the marker, so it works.
rvecs, tvecs are

`VectorOfVectorOfPointF rvecs = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF(); VectorOfVectorOfPointF tvecs = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF();`

cameraMatrix and coeffs are defined like (I'm just guessing about these):

`Matrix<float> cameraMatrix = new(3,3);  Matrix<float> coeffs=new(1,5);`

then filled it with the data I got from OpenCV's calibration utility.
In this form all I get is a nice fat Exception:

"An unhandled exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.Platform.NetStandard.dll: 'OpenCV: 0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size()'
at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, IntPtr funcName, IntPtr errMsg, IntPtr fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)"

Drives me crazy.

I'd like to know where and how to fill cameraMatrix and coeffs using the data I got using the OpenCV calibration utility.

Update: I've managed to load the actual cameraMatrix and camera coeffs using OpenCV's calibration utility. The exception still happens.